# Browse Apache Kylin Cubes

Tags: olap, cube, kylin

We have created Data Model and Cubes in Apache Kylin version 2.0.
We are able to query the tables in the Cube (under Insights tab).
But, we are not able to figure out how to browse the Cube, similar to what happens in SASS.

I want to query Metrics and Dimensions created directly from the Cube. Please let me know how to browse a Cube directly in Kylin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kylin does not expose MDX interface, thus user cannot browser cube directly. Instead, SQL interface is encouraged as it is still the most popular way to query relational data set.

That said, there are ways to enable MDX on Kylin through third party tools to achieve similar experience to SASS. Try google "Kylin MDX" and are few links seem useful.

- http://dekarlab.de/wp/?p=363
- https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kylin-dev/201501.mbox/%3CCABivuamWLTuM3eBAVnj67PWiWAsgTJV+DWKHFOX0b482hVmOdw@mail.gmail.com%3E
- http://tech.youzan.com/kylin-mondrian-saiku/

Comment: We are tryied to browse Kylin Cubes using saiku and Mondrian.

Comment: Thanks for Reply.We are tryied to browse Kylin Cubes using Saiku. 
We are able to run MDX quries from Saiku and Mondrian .
But when we are browsing the Cube, we are getting below error.
IOException: POST failed, error code 500 and response: {"code":"999","data":null,"msg":"Error while executing SQL \"select \"KYLIN_CAL_DT\".\"CAL_DT\" as \"c0\" from \"DEFAULT\".\"KYLIN_CAL_DT\" as \"KYLIN_CAL_DT\" group by \"KYLIN_CAL_DT\".\"CAL_DT\" order by CASE WHEN \"KYLIN_CAL_DT\".\"CAL_DT\" IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 
index (1) must be less than size (1)\n\tat org.apache.kylin.rest.service.QueryService.do

Comment: Such error better report to Kylin mailing list for discussion. Have more space for stacktrace. (http://kylin.apache.org/community/)